# How to count the JSON object's keys as they are not the same

Tags: python, json, loops, testing, automated-tests

I want to get the length of my JSON objects' key values (if we think of it as a dictionary) and count it. I have a Word doc and I apply a text parse operation on this doc and get a JSON object. This doc is a test procedure and it has different Test Cases. I will do some operations on these case infos but I want to have the exact number so I can do it on a loop.

I will provide you the JSON object to make sense of why I want to get this.
So my JSON object is:

```
{
   "Test Case 1": [
      {
         "Test Case": "Test Case 1 : SENSOR_VCC Sinyal İşlemleri  ",
         "Test Step": "Test Step 1",
         "Sub_Tests": [
            {
               "Port": "J7-9",
               "Applied Voltage": "4",
               "Expected Result": 5.0,
               "Tolerance": 0.3
            },
            {
               "Port": "J7-9",
               "Applied Voltage": "3.3",
               "Expected Result": 4.125,
               "Tolerance": 0.3
            },
            {
               "Port": "J7-9",
               "Applied Voltage": "0",
               "Expected Result": 0.0,
               "Tolerance": 0.3
            }
         ]
      }
   ],
   "Test Case 2": [
      {
         "Test Case": "Test Case 2 : REF_0V Sinyal İşlemleri  ",
         "Test Step": "Test Step 1",
         "Sub_Tests": [
            {
               "Port": "J7-15",
               "Applied Voltage": "5",
               "Expected Result": 5.0,
               "Tolerance": 0.3
            },
            {
               "Port": "J7-15",
               "Applied Voltage": "3.3",
               "Expected Result": 3.3,
               "Tolerance": 0.3
            },
            {
               "Port": "J7-15",
               "Applied Voltage": "0",
               "Expected Result": 0.0,
               "Tolerance": 0.3
            }
         ]
      }
   ],
   "Test Case 3": [
      { #goes on&on to the Test Case 19. But it it not constant test case number
```

I tried this code line:

```
print(len(analogOut.procedure['Test Case '][0]))
```

But it gave me this error:

> ```
>      print(len(analogOut.procedure['Test Case '][0]))
> KeyError: 'Test Case '
> ```

Apparently, it takes the argument as a whole so I cannot catch phrases from it.
I would appreciate it if there is anyone to help me with this.

After getting the exact value of how many test cases are there, I will take it into a loop and try to read the values for each Test Case.

I have a code for reading them for just Test Case 1:

```
with open("signal_procedure.json", "r") as file:
    analogOut.procedure = json.load(file)
    print(type(analogOut.procedure))
print(len(analogOut.procedure['Test Case '][0]))
# Getting test cases
analogOut.listof_cases = []
index = 0
for index in analogOut.procedure.keys():
    analogOut.listof_cases.insert(len(analogOut.listof_cases), index)
# getting values of the test case dictionary
analogOut.listof_content = []
index = 0
for index in analogOut.procedure.values():
    analogOut.listof_content.insert(len(analogOut.listof_content), index)

analogOut.applied = {}
for k, v in analogOut.procedure.items():
    analogOut.applied[k] = [[analogOut.listof_content.get("Applied Voltage") for analogOut.listof_content in analogOut.listof_content["Sub_Tests"]] for analogOut.listof_content in v]

print(analogOut.applied)
print("*************")
analogOut.expected = {}
for k, v in analogOut.procedure.items():
    analogOut.expected[k] = [[analogOut.listof_content.get("Expected Result") for analogOut.listof_content in analogOut.listof_content["Sub_Tests"]] for
                  analogOut.listof_content in v]

print(analogOut.expected)
print("*************")
analogOut.tolerance = {}
for k, v in analogOut.procedure.items():
    analogOut.tolerance[k] = [[analogOut.listof_content.get("Tolerance") for analogOut.listof_content in analogOut.listof_content["Sub_Tests"]] for
                   analogOut.listof_content in v]

print(analogOut.tolerance)

    print("******APPLIED IN SPECIFIC TEST CASE*******")
    analogOut.applied_TC = []
    analogOut.applied_TC.insert(len(analogOut.applied.get("Test Case 1")), analogOut.applied.get("Test Case 1"))
    print(analogOut.applied_TC)

    print("******EXPECTED IN SPECIFIC TEST CASE*******")
    analogOut.expected_TC = []
    analogOut.expected_TC.insert(len(analogOut.expected.get("Test Case 1")), analogOut.expected.get("Test Case 1"))
    print(analogOut.expected_TC)

    print("******TOLERANCE IN SPECIFIC TEST CASE*******")
    analogOut.tolerance_TC = []
    analogOut.tolerance_TC.insert(len(analogOut.tolerance.get("Test Case 1")), analogOut.tolerance.get("Test Case 1"))
    print(analogOut.tolerance_TC)


    for channel_index in (CH1, CH2):
        degerler = [float(eleman) for inner_list in applied_TC for middle_list in inner_list for eleman in middle_list]
        for j in degerler:
            analogOut.voltage_DC = j
            analogOut.amplitudeSet(channel_index, analogOut.voltage_DC)
            read_voltage_CH1 = analogOut.amplitudeGet(CH1)
            read_voltage_CH2 = analogOut.amplitudeGet(CH2)
            if analogOut.voltage_DC*0.97 <= read_voltage_CH1 <= analogOut.voltage_DC*1.03:
                print(f"{analogOut.voltage_DC} and {read_voltage_CH1} are equal, true voltage was given!")
            else:
                print(f"{analogOut.voltage_DC} and {read_voltage_CH1} are equal, wrong voltage was given!")
```

So how can I take this into a loop and do the operations for each Case?

Comment: `len(d.keys())`

Comment: So, you are trying to get the length of the list in "Test Case 1"?

Comment: @Wyrmwood - OP seems to want the length of the first value matched (that [0] at the end) and doesn't mention whether there are other keys in the dict that don't match the pattern.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not sure what they are asking. Maybe? `len([_ for _ in d.keys() if "Test Case" in _])`

Comment: @Wyrmwood - that's a good read too. Not sure.

Comment: @Wyrmwood thats exactly what I asked thank you :) However how can I take it into a loop to get the applied,expected and tolerance values of each case?

Answer (score 1):

Dictionaries look for the exact key given, not some sort of pattern. But you could iterate the dictionary and check your own pattern. It appears that you want the list of "Test Case" in the first Test Case X found.

```
tc_len = 0
for key, value in analogOut.items():
    if key.startswith("Test Case "):
        tc_len = len(value)
        break
print(tc_len)
```

Note that python dictionaries retain the insertion order of items, so "first" is the first thing inserted. This is not generally true with JSON where dictionaries are unordered. You can't expect to get the same item every time.

There are a lot of things you can do with the data by iterating each subgroup. For instance

```
analogOut = {
   "Test Case 1": [
      {
         "Test Case": "Test Case 1 : SENSOR_VCC Sinyal İşlemleri  ",
         "Test Step": "Test Step 1",
         "Sub_Tests": [
            {
               "Port": "J7-9",
               "Applied Voltage": "4",
               "Expected Result": 5.0,
               "Tolerance": 0.3
            },
            {
               "Port": "J7-9",
               "Applied Voltage": "3.3",
               "Expected Result": 4.125,
               "Tolerance": 0.3
            },
            {
               "Port": "J7-9",
               "Applied Voltage": "0",
               "Expected Result": 0.0,
               "Tolerance": 0.3
            }
         ]
      }
   ],
   "Test Case 2": [
      {
         "Test Case": "Test Case 2 : REF_0V Sinyal İşlemleri  ",
         "Test Step": "Test Step 1",
         "Sub_Tests": [
            {
               "Port": "J7-15",
               "Applied Voltage": "5",
               "Expected Result": 5.0,
               "Tolerance": 0.3
            },
            {
               "Port": "J7-15",
               "Applied Voltage": "3.3",
               "Expected Result": 3.3,
               "Tolerance": 0.3
            },
            {
               "Port": "J7-15",
               "Applied Voltage": "0",
               "Expected Result": 0.0,
               "Tolerance": 0.3
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}

test_case_count = test_step_count = test_subtest_count = 0

for test_case_key, test_case in analogOut.items():
    if test_case_key.startswith("Test Case "):
        test_case_count += 1
        for test_step in test_case:
            test_step_count += 1
            print("****", test_step["Test Case"], test_step["Test Step"])
            for sub_test in test_step["Sub_Tests"]:
                test_subtest_count += 1
                print(sub_test["Applied Voltage"], sub_test["Expected Result"],
                    sub_test["Tolerance"])

print(test_case_count, test_step_count, test_subtest_count)
```

Comment: Can I use it to get the applied, expected and tolerance values for every Test Cases. Like:         for key, value in analogOut.procedure.items():
            if key.startswith("Test Case "):
                print("******APPLIED IN SPECIFIC TEST CASE*******")
                analogOut.applied_TC = []
                analogOut.applied_TC.insert(len(analogOut.applied.get("Test Case 1")), analogOut.applied.get("Test Case 1"))
           What can I write here other than .get("Test Case 1")? I couldnt write key.startswith("Test Case ")

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking for. The number of test steps per test case? The number of sub tests per test step? Total number of sub tests?

Comment: This JSON object has 19 test cases now. I will be getting the "Applied Voltage": "4", "Expected Result": 5.0, "Tolerance": 0.3 values. These values can be different for every test case so whether it is different or not I need to get these values. So when the loop is for key, value in analogOut.procedure.items():, (btw analogOut.procedure = json.load(file)) I need to write a condition to get into every "Test Case X" like you wrote if key.startswith("Test Case "):. Independent from the number it needs to check/get the Applied Voltage, Expected Result, Tolerance values.

Comment: In your edited code, I can print the values which is great but I cannot access them individually. I have dictionaries which are {'Test Case 1': [['4', '3.3', '0']], 'Test Case 2': [['5', '3.3', '0']], .... and {'Test Case 1': [[5.0, 4.125, 0.0]], 'Test Case 2': [[5.0, 3.3, 0.0]].... and {'Test Case 1': [[0.3, 0.3, 0.3]], 'Test Case 2': [[0.3, 0.3, 0.3]],... these are for applied, expected and tolerance values. Maybe I can access the values from there?